# Node.js https.request stops after a while

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get data from the kanbanery rest api and verything works but after a while the https.request function doesn't work anymore. I don't get any error's just no ouput after 10 times or so

here's my code:

```
setInterval( function() {
    console.log('get tasks');
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            //console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                temp = JSON.parse(chunk);
                tasks = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    tasks[i] = {
                        label: temp[i]['title'],
                        value: indexOfRowContainingId(temp[i]['task_type_id'],tasks2)
                    };
                }
                console.log(tasks);
                send_event('tasks', { items: tasks });
            });    
        });
    req.on('error', function(error){
        console.log("Error: "+error);
    });
    req.end();
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Does anybody see the problem?

Comment: Does kanbanery need an api key to be sent with the request? That might be why it does not send anything after 10 requests

Comment: There may be an upper limit to the number of request you can do in a particular session. Check out their API and look for that.

Comment: I'm sending a api key in the options value. There's nothing in there docs about a max request per session. Here's a link to the documentation: http://support.kanbanery.com/customer/portal/articles/1137675-api-version-1-3